# R's merge function to merge dataframes by rownames

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge two dataframes that have a different number of rows, but matching rownames. Here's what I have:

```
> head(counts.0hpi$counts)
                   r1      r2      r3      r4      r5
Cluster_1     588.148 621.756 596.124 618.485 590.202
Cluster_10    469.730 509.523 523.748 476.219 518.317
Cluster_1000  117.801 115.956 121.915  95.635 123.563
Cluster_10000 519.337 477.910 486.273 477.311 498.591
Cluster_10001 385.777 382.447 393.380 366.418 389.452
Cluster_10002  10.000  17.000   7.000  14.000  10.000

> head(counts.72hpi$counts)
                   r1      r2      r3      r4      r5
Cluster_1      35.083  31.018  39.044  32.033  26.045
Cluster_10    132.370 120.348 100.381 109.481 117.742
Cluster_100    67.274  77.491  56.541  56.527  56.630
Cluster_10000  39.784  32.709  24.529  25.004  23.961
Cluster_10001   6.000   6.000  10.000   9.000  10.000
Cluster_10002   4.904   7.963   4.000   4.000   7.962

> all <- merge(counts.0hpi$counts, counts.72hpi$counts, by = union(rownames(counts.0hpi$counts), rownames(counts.72hpi$counts)))
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns
```

What did I get wrong? Thanks a lot

Comment: The [helpfile for `merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) says you can specify `"row.names"` or the number `0` to do the type of `merge` you're attempting. i.e. `merge(counts.0hpi$counts, counts.72hpi$counts, by = "row.names")`

Comment: Looks a lot easier indeed, together with the option `all=TRUE` it works like a charm! Thanks.

`all <- merge(counts.0hpi$counts, counts.72hpi$counts, by = "row.names",all=TRUE)`